# Making Azimuthal equal-area (Hem.) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

[image]

Like this attached image, I tried many times in QGIS but cannot get this look.

How do I make this map in QGIS?

Comment: https://geosupportsystem-se.translate.goog/2018/03/06/fler-projektioner-i-qgis/?_x_tr_sl=sv&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To substantiate the comment/link by @BERA, you can create a custom projection using Menu  <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Custom Projections</kbd>. Enter a name for your projection, set `Format` to `Proj String` and paste this string: `+proj=ortho`. HIt OK, than change your project CRS to the custom CRS you created and you'll get a orthographic projection centered at [NULL island](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island) (intersection of prime meridian and equator).

You can center the projection on any coordinate by adding a string, e.g. for lon= 69 S and lat = 17 W (South America): `+lon_0=-69 +lat_0=-17`

[image]

[image]

To have to different projections one next to other like in the last screenshot above, create a new print layout, add two map items and set a different CRS for both in the item properties. You could also paste the proj string directly here to create an ad hoc custom projection:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Appreciate, it is a detailed tutorial.